# Vue Js - How to get detail page view when clicked on input field

Tags: javascript, vue.js, events, input

I am new to Vuejs and currently I wanted to show the the detail page view when I clicked on input field

```
 <div class="form-group row">
 <label for="name" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Name</label>
 <div class="col-sm-10">
 <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" required autocomplete="name" autofocus placeholder="Name" v-model="form.name">
 <span class="invalid-feedback d-block" role="alert" v-if="form.errors.has('name')" v-text="form.errors.get('name')"></span>
 </div>
 </div>
```

Above is code of my input field name and I want to show detail of input field when I clicked on it, I have also attached the screen shot of my view where I wanted to click and show the detail page view

[image]

If I click on u-blox field I wanted to show the detail view. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

The question is not very much clear. Maybe you can share some more code or maybe a fiddle for better help. From what I understand from the question, you can either opt to use a routing-based approach. Or if things are to be kept simple, simply render a  for detail view conditionally using the v-if directive.

```
    <div class="form-group row">
        <label for="name" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Name</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
           <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" required autocomplete="name" autofocus placeholder="Name" v-model="form.name">
           <span class="invalid-feedback d-block" role="alert" v-if="form.errors.has('name')" v-text="form.errors.get('name')"></span>
       </div>
   </div>
   <div v-if="showDetailsView">
       Details View template or Component can be rendered here.
   </div>
```

The `showDetailsView` variable can be toggled through a click listener bound to the u-blox element.

Please refer https://router.vuejs.org/ for Vue-Router and https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/conditional.html#v-if for Conditional Rendering.